# Each $(R,S)$-bimodule is a left $R \otimes_k S^{op}$-module

Tags: homological-algebra

I am trying to understand and fill the gaps of Rotman's proof (in his homological algebra text). This approach is different from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/185201/968391) ("Post 1") and is more complete than this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/942896/968391) ("Post 2").

I understand everthing about the proof except showing that multiplication is well defined.

### 1. Definition and preliminary notes about Rotman's text

Let $k$ be a commutative ring. $R$ is a k-algebra if $R$ is a $k$-module satisfying
$$ a(rs) = (ar)s = r(as) $$
for all $a \in k$ and $r,s \in R$

Note that rings are assume to be unital and modules are assumed to have the property $1_R m = m$.

### 2. Result I'm trying to understand

[image]

[image]

### 3. My partial understanding

Instead of constructing the trilinear function suggested, it seems easier to me (as in the second linked post) to construct a bilinear function $f_m : R \times S^{op} \to M$ defined by $f_m(r,s) = rms$.

Post 1 suggests that we **must assume** that $am = ma$ with $m \in M$ and $a \in k$ when we regard M as a $k$-Module. But Rotman mentions this nowhere, and I didn't understand Post 1's comments about why this must be so.

Using this assumption, we clearly have $f_m$ bilinear for each $m$ so that $f_m$ extends to $\hat f_m : R \otimes S^{op} \to M$. We also have $f_{m + m'} = f_m + f_{m'}$, so we see that $(r \otimes x) m = rms$ is well defined.

### 4. Questions

1. As I mentioned above, I want a clearly understanding of why $am = ma$ for $a \in k$ and $m \in M$. Does this follow from Rotman's definition of a $k$-algebra, or is this an assumption he left out?
2. Rotman tries to show multiplication is well-defined by constructed a k-trilinear map. I assume what he's doing is using the universal property to show that $\phi : R \otimes S^{op} \otimes M \to M$ is well-defined. Then the desired multiplication function is

$$ (R \otimes S^{op}) \times M \xrightarrow{h} R \otimes S^{op} \otimes M \xrightarrow{\phi} M $$
where $h$ is the tensor product. Is this right?

Comment: For 1., the answer is given in the first link you provided. This is indeed an error in Rotman's book. A $(R,S)$-bimodule is the same thing as an $R\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} S^{op}$-module, but if $R$ and $S$ both have $k$-algebra structures, we must add the assumption that they act the same way on the module $M$. For 2., $h$ is indeed the canonical bilinear map from the cartesian product to the tensor product.